# How to use parentheses in .bat files, set command and IF EXIST

Tags: batch-file

Ok, I have  batch file, just a simple one that hides and unhides folders.

I don't see why it cannot seem to execute accordingly;

Here is extended sample code:

```
@echo off
color a
title Folder/Drive hider Service

:jiki
echo Loading...
TIMEOUT /T 2 >nul
goto inputs
:inputs
echo Enabling security...
TIMEOUT /T 2 >nul
cls
goto menu

:menu
if EXIST "%~dp0\Encryption" (set status=Folder is locked.)
if EXIST "%~dp0\Logan_Documents" (set status=Folder is unlocked, to open it, enter open as your            `action.)`
cls
echo.
echo STATUS: %status%
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------
echo  FOLDER PROTECTOR by Logan 
echo ----------------------------------------
echo.
echo  Lock      = Lock the folder(s)
echo  Unlock    = Unlock the folder(s)
echo  Credits   = For more info
echo  V         = Display your current version
echo  Exit      = Close the program
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------
echo For more info, just ask Logan!
echo ----------------------------------------
echo.
echo Select your action, %USERNAME%.
echo.
set /p "menu=>"
if /I %menu%== lock goto lock
if /I %menu%== unlock goto unlock
if /I %menu%== credits goto credits
if /I %menu%== v goto version
if /I %menu%== exit goto exit
goto invalid
```

and also a lot more, and every time I go to execute the script, it just leaves the status variable blank.

Here's what I've tried.

- Reconfiguring all variables through a port, which then sorts based on `if exist`. doesn't work, just leaves status blank.
- Using different variables. (Kinda stupid but I didn't want to think that I have all these errors because of a small typo.) Still left error blank.

Appreciate all efforts to resolve my problem and get this program working!
-Logan

Answer (score 2):

`if exist` should work fine exactly as you use it. You don't strictly need the quotes, since the names don't include spaces. Also you don't need the parentheses since it is a single command.

But then again, it should work with them as well (I actually tested this), so the only thing I can imagine is that the files or folders are not found because the script is running in the wrong directory. After all you use just the names without any path, so the current directory should contain those files.

The 'current directory' isn't necessarily the directory in which the script is saved. If you are in 'C:\Foo' and you call 'C:\Bar\Script.bat', the current directory will still be 'C:\Foo'. The same goes for starting scripts through a shortcut.

To try this, you can use `echo %CD%` in your script to echo the current directory.

As a possible solution, you can use `%~dp0` to use the actual directory in which the batch script is saved, so you always have a starting point to start from:

```
REM Check if 'Encryption' exists in the same folder as the batch file.
if EXIST "%~dp0\Encryption" (set status=Folder is locked.)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer my question, I appreciate your help and the test for current directory specifications etc. **All** the files I will be modifying are located on the same Drive; F:\. I have tried your code (much more promising than my current code ;)) and still no luck with this process, I will include more code for you to take a look at and hopefully spot the error.

Comment: The batch script itself is also in F:\?

Comment: Yes, all files are in F:\, a little bit stuck on how I would fix this. It just says 'File not Found'.

Answer (score 0):

probably neither of the `if`s are true, maybe because the active directory is not what you think it is. you can test this easily by inserting a `set status=none` above the `if`s. or insert `dir` to see what the scrips actually sees at this point.